# continuous deployment for stateful apache flink application on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to run an apache flink (1.11.1) streaming application on kubernetes. With a filesystem state backend saving to s3. Checkpointing to s3 is working

```
args:
  - "standalone-job"
    - "-s"
    - "s3://BUCKET_NAME/34619f2862ce3e5fc91d80eae13a434a/chk-4/_metadata"
    - "--job-classname"
    - "com.abc.def.MY_JOB"
    - "--kafka-broker"
    - "KAFKA_HOST:9092"
```

#### So the problem that I'm facing is:

- I have to select the previous state dir manually. Is there a possibility to make it better?
- The job increments the chk dir but it does not use the checkpoint. Means I throw a new event when I have seen an event for the first time and store it to a `ListState<String>` whenever I deploy via Gitlab a newer version of my application it again throws this event.
- Why do I have to enable the checkpointing explicitly in my code when I have defined the state.backend to filesystem? `env.enableCheckpointing(Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());` and `env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);`

Answer (score 2):

- You might be happier with [Ververica Platform: Community Edition](https://www.ververica.com/getting-started), which raises the level of abstraction to the point where you don't have to deal with the details at this level. It has an API that was designed with CI/CD in mind.
- I'm not sure I understand your second point, but it's normal that your job will rewind and reprocess some data during recovery. Flink does not guarantee exactly once processing, but rather exactly once semantics: each event will affect the state being managed by Flink exactly once. This is done by rolling back to the offsets in the most recent checkpoint, and rolling back all of the other state to what it had been after consuming all of the data up to those offsets.
- Having a state backend is necessary as a place to store your job's working state while the job is running. If you don't enable checkpointing, then the working state won't be checkpointed, and can not be recovered. However, as of Flink 1.11, you can enable checkpointing via the config file, using

```
execution.checkpointing.interval: 60000
execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention: RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION
```

Comment: Thanks David. Can the Vervica Platform Helm Chart been used for a corporate (streaming application running on k8s internally means not public cloud offering)? Didnt seen any restrictions in the [user agreement](https://www.ververica.com/legal-forms/community-edition-license-agreement).

Comment: Yes, it can be used for commercial and production use -- see https://www.ververica.com/blog/announcing-ververica-platform-community-edition -- so long as you observe the restrictions in the license agreement. community-edition@ververica.com for more info.

Comment: And any idea or thoughts how it would look without VP:CE? Is there a chance to have a CI/CD with just apache flink?

Comment: It's certainly feasible to do CI/CD yourself on top of open source Flink, but the deployment process involves several steps, any of which might potentially fail. So it's a bit complex to fully automate.

Comment: Whether Kubernetes preStop and initContainer functionalities would help for this? ie - In preStop, we can invoke the REST API to stop the job with checkpoints and in initContainer we can write something to fetch the latest checkpoint location and set it to some env variable for the main container?

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to deploy workloads to kubernetes, simple YAML files, Helm Chart, and Operator.

Upgrading a stateful Flink job is not as simple as upgrading a stateless service, you only need to update the binary file and restart.

Upgrading Flink Job you need to take a savepoint or get the latest checkpoint dir and then update binary and finally resubmit your job, in this case, I think simple YAML files and Helm Chart cannot help you to achieve this, you should consider implementing a Flink Operator to do the upgrading job.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flink-on-k8s-operator

Comment: Whether Kubernetes preStop and initContainer functionalities would help for this? ie - In preStop, we can invoke the REST API to stop the job with checkpoints and in initContainer we can write something to fetch the latest checkpoint location and set it to some env variable for the main container?